# AD B2C non-interactive / headless authentication using resource owner password credentials flow

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am using the `Azure AD B2C` service for the authentication. I having a use case where the user authentication has to be done in `non-interactive / headless manner`.
I need to send the username and password to `AD B2C using Graph API` to validate the user and get the `id token` and `access token`.

In the AD B2C documentation under [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/application-types#daemonsserver-side-applications), it says the above mentioned use case is not supported, instead the use case can be achieved using client credentials flow.

But, I have tried using the [resource owner password credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=app-reg-ga) to achieve this use case. It is working for me.

Is this approach is advisable to achieve the non-interactive / headless authentication user flow?

[image]

Update:

I have a Web API protected using AD B2C, those APIs is consumed from Web Application and also from external application (can be a Desktop application, another Web API).

For web application, we can use interactive AD B2C sign-in flow for the authentication.

For external application (can be a Desktop application, another Web API), We need to authenticate in non-interactive / headless manner. For this can we use the ROPC flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limitation is specifically for headless/long-running Applications. You are referring to **User** authentication, whereby we do support [ROPC flow for Native Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/ropc-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga) only. ROPC will not work for Web Apps. For Web Apps you must use interactive authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I have a Web API protected using AD B2C, those APIs is consumed from Web Application and also from external application (can be a Desktop application, another Web API).

For web application, we can use interactive AD B2C sign-in flow for the authentication.
For external application (can be a Desktop application, another Web API), We need to authenticate in non-interactive / headless manner. For this can we use the ROPC flow?

Comment: For desktop/native apps, you can use ROPC yes. You cannot use ROPC from web app or  javascript SPA app. For web api to api calls, they should use [AAD Client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

Comment: Is there any specific reason there to not to use the ROPC user flow for web API to Web API calls?

Comment: For Web API to API calls, use the AAD client credentials flow.